# null values received in Post method from ajax call ASP.net 4.5

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

in my

```
  public class ValuesController : ApiController
```

I have a Post method :

```
 public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
            string a = "asdsad";
        }
```

I created a small HTML with a button on it, When I press on it, im using `$.ajax` to call the `Post` method using :

```
function myfunc() 
             {


    $.ajax({
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: '{"value":"on"}',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    app.log("device control succeeded");
                },
                error: function(){
                    app.log("Device control failed");
                },
                processData: false,
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:49558/api/values',
            });
        }
```

The problem is the `Post` method receives in the `string value - null`

If there is something wrong with this approach:

what is the best way to send data via post method using ajax?

Comment: Try `data: {value:"on"},`

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the value like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/api/values',
    data: '=on',
    success: function (data) {

    },
});
```

Notice the `=` in the data section before the actual value.

And if you wanted to use JSON, you would have started with a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

that your controller action would have taken as parameter:

```
public void Post(MyViewModel model)
{
    // use model.Value here
}
```

which you would have invoked like that:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/api/values',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ value: 'on' }),
    success: function (data) {

    },
});
```